# Pytorch example from Deep Reinforcement learning in action running too slow

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am running an example from the book *Deep reinforcement learning in action; by Alexander Zai, Brandon Brown* but my code runs extremely slowly and for the life of me I cannot understand why.

The only difference I can find from my example to its example is the fact that I am using a different game; however, slow move generations should not be the problem as I can use the same game with tabular methods and easily train it on 500000 samples in just a few minutes. But as soon as neural networks are involved Training only on 50000 takes more than a couple hours.

I am using both experience replay and a target network.

My code is as follows:

```py
def train(nGames, lGames, batchSize, replaySize, learning_rate, syncFreq):
    epsilon = .1 # the initial exploration rate
    gamma   = .9 # the discount of the rewards

    replay    = deque(maxlen=replaySize) # initialize the experience replay buffer

    loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    # This qFunction is defined further into the question
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(qFunction.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    j        = 0
    losses   = []

    # Actions that we actually send to the game
    actionIndexed = {0: "U", 1: "D", 2: "L", 3: "R", 4: "PASS"}

    for e in range(nGames):

        progressBar(e, nGames) # Just a progress bar function. Not relevant

        game  = DayGathering() # This is my own game
        state = game.observation() # This just extracts a dictionary with relevant information about the game

        # start playing the game
        i = 0
        done = False
        while not done:
            # agent taking an action with epsilon-greedy strategy
            if np.random.random() < epsilon:
                actionIndex = np.random.choice(range(5))
                action      = actionIndexed[actionIndex]
            else:
                # Select the action with the largest Q-value
                stateC      = converter(state)
                qValues     = qFunction(stateC).data.numpy()
                actionIndex = np.argmax(qValues)
                action      = actionIndexed[actionIndex]

            # advancing the state of the board
            # This functions just move to the next state
            game.playerTurn(action)
            game.boardTurn()
            newState = game.observation()

            # checking for rewards
            reward = rewardFunction(newState)

            # check if the current game is terminal. This happens if i = lGame
            # - 1 or if the agent is caught outside during night fall
            if i == lGames - 1 or outsideAtNight(newState):
                done = True
            else:
                done = False

            # saving the (state, action, newstate, reward) values in the experience replay buffer
            replay.append((stateC, actionIndex, newState, reward, done))

            # when we get to the batch size we train the network
            if len(replay) > batchSize:
                miniBatch     = random.sample(replay, batchSize)
                stateBatch    = torch.cat([sC for sC, _, _, _, _ in miniBatch])
                actionBatch   = torch.Tensor([actionIndex for _, actionIndex, _, _, _ in miniBatch])
                rewardBatch   = torch.Tensor([reward for _, _, _, reward, _ in miniBatch])
                newStateBatch = torch.cat([converter(newState) for _, _, newState, _, _ in miniBatch])
                doneBatch     = torch.Tensor([done for _, _, _, _, done in miniBatch])

                # use the target network to bootstrap
                with torch.no_grad():
                    newStateQ = qFunctionTarget(newStateBatch)

                # compute the predition of the networks for R + gamma*MaxRewards
                Y = rewardBatch + gamma * (1 - doneBatch)*torch.max(newStateQ,dim=1)[0]

                # Compute the discounted rewards using the first original network
                stateQ = qFunction(stateBatch).gather(dim=1, index=actionBatch.long().unsqueeze(dim=1)).squeeze()

                # compute the loss of the model and backpropagate
                loss = loss_fn(stateQ, Y.detach())
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                # keeping track of the losses
                losses.append(loss.item())
                optimizer.step()

                # periodically copy parameters to the target network
                if j % syncFreq == 0:
                    qFunctionTarget.load_state_dict(qFunction.state_dict())

            # advance the state of the game
            state = newState

            i += 1
            j += 1 # advance j
    return losses
```

That was the main training loop. Now for other things that appear in the previous code

**The neural network**

```py
qFunction = torch.nn.Sequential(torch.nn.Linear(426, 1024),
                                torch.nn.ReLU(),
                                torch.nn.Linear(1024, 512),
                                torch.nn.ReLU(),
                                torch.nn.Linear(512, 5),
                                )
qFunctionTarget = copy.deepcopy(qFunction)
qFunctionTarget.load_state_dict(qFunction.state_dict())
```

**The converter from observations to the ann input**: I don't think this is very relevant bu I decided to include it any way. Basically the game is a grid world and we simply convert the observation to an array of zeros and ones indicating positions on the board. After creating this board we perturb it with noise.

```py
def converter(observation):
    px, py = observation["player position"]
    playerBitBoard = torch.zeros([9, 9])
    playerBitBoard[py, px] = 1

    # making the bit boards for all apples
    a1x, a1y = observation["apple 1"]
    apple1BitBoard = torch.zeros([9, 9])
    apple1BitBoard[a1y, a1x] = 1

    a2x, a2y = observation["apple 2"]
    apple2BitBoard = torch.zeros([9, 9])
    apple2BitBoard[a2y, a2x] = 1

    a3x, a3y = observation["apple 3"]
    apple3BitBoard = torch.zeros([9, 9])
    apple3BitBoard[a3y, a3x] = 1

    # making the bit board for the key. Note that the key will have NONE values
    # in its position. They must be dealt with. Current solution put all values
    # in the key board equal to zero
    key = observation["key position"]
    keyBitBoard = torch.zeros([9, 9])
    if key:
        kx, ky = key
        keyBitBoard[ky, kx] = 1

    # making the time features
    t = observation["time until nigth"]
    timeBitBoard = torch.zeros(21)
    timeBitBoard[t] = 1

    # now we join all in a single array
    return torch.cat([playerBitBoard.reshape(81),
                      apple1BitBoard.reshape(81),
                      apple2BitBoard.reshape(81),
                      apple3BitBoard.reshape(81),
                      keyBitBoard.reshape(81),
                      timeBitBoard]).reshape((1, 426)) + torch.rand((1, 426))/100
```

Comment: Sanity check though, did you use GPU?

Comment: @AerysS. Well GPU was not available in my laptop. It is however available in a remote server I can use where I am currently running my code. However I am rather new to pytorch so I am not sure how to do that. Moreover the example from the book also does not use GPU so I though I do be fine not doing so

Comment: If you experience significantly slow training time using Neural Net without GPU, it is perfectly normal. Your NN is not small after all: it is medium-sized.

Comment: @AerysS. I should also state that at first I was using and crafted features such as the distance from the player to some other objects which allowed me to work with small networks (such as 8 input features) and the training was also significantly slow. A bit faster than it currently is but also really slow

Comment: 8 input features do not change the 4096, 1024, 512 you are using a lot. Try decreasing this number to 32, 16 or lower. If you still see it's low then it's probably something wrong with the code, else it's the Neural Net.

Comment: @AerysS. Sorry, I did not express myself well in the previous comment. I have used smaller networks when reducing the number of input features (about the size you suggested) and it ran  little faster but it was still much slower than what I was expecting. That is one of the reasons I have not yet used GPU acceleration since I know that there is something else holding back the training significantly

Comment: @AerysS. I have just put all of my models and tensor in the GPU. Using `top`and `nvidia-smi` I confirmed that the process is in fact running in the GPU and the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

That converter thing looks slow, maybe you can vectorize it.